# Getting more info on Capistrano tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundle, bundler

I'm get a Capistrano recipe to work with Bundler and a Rails (3.0.3) app but having trouble with some basic functionality.

Following the [Bundler docs](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html) for "Automatic deployment with Capistrano", I'm trying to get more info on a task but for some reason it "doesn't exist"...

```
$ cap -e bundle:install
The task `bundle:install' does not exist.
```

The Capistrano (2.5.19) gem is installed and I'm trying to execute that command from the root of my project on the client (not the server).

in fact cap -T doesn't show anything related to 'bundle' or 'install'

```
$ cap -T
cap deploy               # Deploys your project.
cap deploy:check         # Test deployment dependencies.
cap deploy:cleanup       # Clean up old releases.
cap deploy:cold          # Deploys and starts a `cold' application.
cap deploy:migrate       # Run the migrate rake task.
cap deploy:migrations    # Deploy and run pending migrations.
cap deploy:pending       # Displays the commits since your last deploy.
cap deploy:pending:diff  # Displays the `diff' since your last deploy.
cap deploy:restart       # Restarts your application.
cap deploy:rollback      # Rolls back to a previous version and restarts.
cap deploy:rollback:code # Rolls back to the previously deployed version.
cap deploy:setup         # Prepares one or more servers for deployment.
cap deploy:start         # Start the application servers.
cap deploy:stop          # Stop the application servers.
cap deploy:symlink       # Updates the symlink to the most recently deployed ...
cap deploy:update        # Copies your project and updates the symlink.
cap deploy:update_code   # Copies your project to the remote servers.
cap deploy:upload        # Copy files to the currently deployed version.
cap deploy:web:disable   # Present a maintenance page to visitors.
cap deploy:web:enable    # Makes the application web-accessible again.
cap invoke               # Invoke a single command on the remote servers.
cap shell                # Begin an interactive Capistrano session.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you include the recipe in your deploy.rb file?

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

Comment: That's it! I didn't realize 'cap -T' would *vary* depending on what's in `deploy.rb`.  I guess I thought of it more as a glorified man page. Any docs that might help me conceptualize this a little better?

Comment: You've probably figured this out on your own by now, but...  deploy.rb is the configuration that drives the cap command.  Recipes that aren't included in the configuration won't be available to the cap command, and so won't show up when you ask it what recipes it has available.